# Javascript not loading in internet explorer 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am getting this error no matter what i try:

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
onload.js, line 1 character 1
```

It works great on every browser except IE 10 (compatibility view doesn't work either)

After playing a little with the Debugger i found that the content on onload.js, reported by IE is:

```
<HTML>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
</HTML>
```

That is so stupid ... why is IE seeing this content instead of the original JavaScript? Same issue happens with CSS, it shows this code instead of the normal content.

The links are correct, the embedding is correct. If i access the JavaScript source url manually in IE it works, i get the download dialog and the content is there. Looks like the embedding is not working.

Thanks
Radu

Comment: Does it work in other versions of Internet Explorer? Have you set a `doctype`? It's been a long while since I last had to deal with IE, but I seem to remember it being a bit weird, thrown into quirks mode, by the omission of `doctype`s before.

Comment: Have you tried some different PC with IE 10? On my project, there are a few people having issue with scripts very similar to yours (not sure about content, but error is the same). But I can't reproduce it at all. Same as other IE 10 users have no issues like that.

Comment: That looks probably like the default content for an empty page. Two possibilities I can see: (1) IE is failing to process the received data properly or (2) your server is sending invalid data to IE. To help see which, check in the Response body section of IE's dev tools Network tab. If you can't get any joy with that, try an external tool like Fiddler to help diagnose the root of the problem. Whatever IE's reputation, this is not normal behaviour so my guess is that there's something odd at the server level. What happens if you use a different browser but spoof the User Agent string to be IE?

Comment: @FAngel it looks like on other pc are working and on others no. Spudley, i can't test anymore, ie crashed and on restart everything is fine... So weird, i will try to replicate the issue.